# How to show progress based on days interval dynamically

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have to display progress bar based on day  interval  suppose that i have given start days and end days so we have to show progress in progress bar in such manner so that if you will 1-3 days then there should fill same progress 3 to 6 we should fill same progress ...and  like this .

Given start date and end date  based on that I have followed  below steps
1 . find total number of days then 
2 find  days difference between todays date and start date 
3 tried to get degree diff between today days and no of days left based one that I set mProgress.setProgress(degrees);.

```
private void displayProgressView() {
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
    final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
    mProgress.setProgress(0);   // Main Progress
    mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(360); // Secondary Progress
    mProgress.setMax(360); // Maximum Progress
    mProgress.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
    int noOfDaysLeft = noOfDaysLeft();
    final int degrees = getDregeesFordays(totalDays() - noOfDaysLeft);
    textView.setText(noOfDaysLeft() + "\nday" + (noOfDaysLeft() == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    mProgress.setProgress(degrees);

 }

here is  date 
"startDate": "2019-09-12T15:48:12.293Z",
 "endDate": "2019-10-12T08:19:00.710Z",
```

i want to set progress based on multiple of 3 like if we have days diff is 1,2,3 then it should show same progress then 4,5,6 then it less secondly  progress and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Get epoch time in unit of seconds. I use [OffsetDateTime(ThreeTen)](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
val offset = OffsetDateTime.now().offset

val startDateEpoch = [your starting date in LocalDateTime unit].toEpochSecond(offset)
val endDateEpoch = [your end date in LocalDateTime unit].toEpochSecond(offset)
```

2. Calculate `result = endDateEpoch - startDateEpoch`
3. Translate it to days

```
eg. result = 500000

timeDifference = result / (3600 * 24)

... additional algorithm
```

4. Conditional check for progressBar

```
if(timeDifference  >= 1 && timeDifference <= 3) doA()

else if(timeDifference  >= 4 && timeDifference <= 7) doB()

...additional algorithm
```

**Update : How to build LocalDateTime unit**

```
val dayOfMonth = 23
val year = 2001
val month = 3

val hour = 0
val minute = 0

val myDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth)

val myTime = LocalTime.of(hour, minute)

val startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(myDate, myTime)
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i dont want to consider time only date i want to consider cant be online condition for  mProgress.setProgress(degrees);

Comment: So you want if starting date 27 Sept 23.00 and endDate 28 Sept 03.00, it counts as 1 day?

Comment: yes @nfl-x  could you please suggest Conditional check for progressBar this can be one line condition ?

Comment: i want set progress degree value 3 interval based on days left ?

Comment: Check update for day issue. I hope it intuitive enough.

Comment: i am confused about condition could you please help me about condition ? i mean there will no else condition ?

Comment: Consider update that part of your question so it easier to understand cause I think that already solved in step 4.